# CSS hover dropdown, selects first link on touch

Tags: html, css, hover

I made a simple dropdown menu which is triggered on hover.
My problem is that on touch-devices, if I click on the lower part of the div (so that my touch is overlapping the hidden dropdown menu) the first link/element in the dropdown gets selected, and my browser navigates to that link.

on #dropDownMenu i have set height and opacity to 0 and display: none; and opposite upon hovering #menu (mainly the h4-tag)

```css
#dropDownMenu {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #555555;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
#Menu:hover #dropDownMenu {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu">
  <h4>Menu</h4>
  <div id="dropDownMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Main</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/1">link1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/2">link2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works great on a computer tho

Comment: Can you include any JavaScript or CSS that you're using?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42068197/6886695